# Is it grammatical correct that a exclamation links a comma?

Tags: symbols

[missing 11-year-old girl](https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEKiuO7h269JxCxdF7ybO-bEqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen)

> "Nothing in her phone indicated she was planning to leave!," Jonie
>   Barnett said on Facebook.

Comment: The comma question aside, I would not use an exclamation point there anyway.